# Annotate matplotlib graphs with Datapoints

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to annotate the data points with their values next to the points on the plot.
I have a dataframe `dfWaits` like this

```
waitEvent       instance    gc cr block 3-way       gc current block 3-way      log file sync
snapDate                            
2015-Jul-01     AAA             NaN                     2                       9       
2015-Jul-01     BBB             NaN                     2                       8
2015-Jul-03     AAA             NaN                     1                       9
2015-Jul-03     BBB             1                       2                       8
2015-Jun-29     AAA             NaN                     2                       8
2015-Jun-29     BBB             NaN                     2                       8
```

I want to draw a simple line chart using matplotlib

```
dfWaits[dfWaits.instance == 'AAA'].plot()
```

It does generate the graph with `snapDate` against the x-axis but I would like to annotate the graph with
values on the y-axis for columns `gc cr block 3-way`,`gc current block 3-way` and `log file sync`

Comment: how would you like to do with `NaN` in `gc cr block 3-way`?

Comment: Thanks Jianxun ,Maybe ignore those values